# Parsing JSON string via Jquery Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, json, parsing

Hey all Here is my code:

```
function SuccessOccur(data, status, req) {
    if (status == "success") {
       var xml = req.responseText.toString();
       console.log(xml);
       var jSON = $(xml).find('empResult').text();
       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jSON);
       console.log(obj.firstName);
    }
}
```

Oddly enough I get this as a value:

```
undefined
```

If I just put this:

```
console.log(obj);
```

Then I would get all the values:

[image]

So, what am I missing?

Comment: *"what am I missing?"* `0: Object`

Answer (score 5):

`obj` is not an object, it's an array, that's why it's in `[]` brackets with a `0` as the key, and a given length of `1` in the console output you've posted. Arrays are accessed like this

```
console.log(obj[0].firstName);
```